# How I can delete the template form when I have duplicate web form?

Tags: jquery

This is the part of jquery:

```
var htmlTempItem2 = $('div[data-id="divPopupControl"] div[data-id="Detail"]').html();
$('div[data-id="divPopupControl"] div[data-id="Detail"] div[id="ItemDetails"]  div[class="panel-collapse collapse"] ').remove();

 $.map(data.d, function (item) {
   console.log("round " + y);
   var htmlAppend2 = jQuery("<div data-type='TempItem'></div>").html(htmlTempItem2)

   .find('div[id="ItemDetails"]')
   .attr('id' + y, 'ItemDetails' + y)
   .html('')
   .parents("div[data-type=TempItem] ").html();

   $('div[data-id="divPopupControl"] div[data-id="Detail"]').append(htmlTempItem2);

   $('div[data-id="divPopupControl"] div[data-id="Detail"]').find('div[id="ItemDetails"]')
   .removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'ItemDetails' + y);

   $('div[data-id="divPopupControl"] div[data-id="Detail"]').find('div[data-type="txtTitleNumber"]')
   .removeAttr('data-type').attr('data-type' + y, 'txtTitleNumber' + y);

   console.log("template : " + htmlTempItem2);
   console.log("Current html : " + $('div[data-id="divPopupControl"] div[data-id="Detail"]').html());  y++;
```

This is Part Of HTML form:

```
<div class="panel-group" data-id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a id="Header" class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#ItemDetails" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ItemDetails">
        Item Number #
     </a>
     </h4>
     </div>
    </div>

<div data-id="Detail">
  <div id="ItemDetails" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div style="margin: 2px; background-color: white; padding: 10px; max-height: 500px; overflow:auto;">
          <div class="spacer-custom"></div>
            <div class="form-inline" role="form">
              <div class="form-group col-xs-2 left">
                <label class="control-label body-blue">Title No: </label>
                 </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div data-type="txtTitleNumber"></div>
               </div>
              </div>
               <div class="spacer-custom"></div>
               <div class="form-inline" role="form">
               <div class="col-xs-10" style="text-align:right">
                 <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="btnClose" data-ResourceProviderKey="btnClose" data-dismiss="modal" />
                 <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="btnSave" data-ResourceProviderKey="btnSave" />
                </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Hello guys, 
Can I using htmlTempItem and htmlTempItem2 in different called TempItem generate? How I can delete the template form? because this is looping with htmlTempItem

```
console.log("template : " + htmlTempItem2);
console.log("Current html : " + $('div[data-id="divPopupControl"] div[data-id="Detail"]').html());
```

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking or what the specific problem is. Explain what this code is supposed to do and what it is doing differently than expected. See [ask]

Comment: I using accordion loopinh data from DB, so now accordion can be display, but problem is all prompt up from on top.. This output still have template html, i want to remove the template one..

Comment: this is the output. https://gyazo.com/2ce03d1b52bbcb66ec05a3af52a45973